# how do I use this in a formal essay?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing an essay for my English class and I want to use "You're personality is crap" but in a nice and school appropriate way, if it is possible?

Comment: I would concentrate on **your** grammar, if I were you.

Comment: *Your personality is bad* is polite enough.

Answer (score 1):

People who say things like "your personality is crap" may have a bit of a personality problem themselves.

If you want really do need to say something unpleasant about somebody, I have three suggestions to make your comments less offensive:

- it will sound less like a blanket criticism and more like you are trying to help if you try to be a bit more specific, for example "you are uncommunicative" or "you are self-centred"
- use indirection: "some people say that..."  to make it sound like you are merely reporting the opinion of others rather than making a personal criticism.
- use adverbs to water it down: "you can be **rather** moody **at times**"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  As is likely in your own native language, in English there are probably dozens (if not hundreds) of "nice" ways to suggest someone has an unpleasant personality.  Some of the more polite versions:

> You are an unpleasant person.
>
> I find your personality objectionable.
>
> You have a difficult nature.
>
> You have a disagreeable disposition.

Less polite:

> You are annoying.
>
> I don't think much of your personality.
>
> You are kind of a jerk.

There are, of course, many even less polite.